# Jquery: Ajax call is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using Jquery to count the clicks and keypresses by the users.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var countClick = 0;
    var keyClick = 0;


    $("body").mousedown(function(){
        countClick ++;          
    });


    $("body").keypress(function(){
         keyClick ++;               
    });


    $("body").bind('keyup', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode >= 37 && e.keyCode <= 40){
          keyClick ++;
        }
    }); 


});
```

Now, I want to send this to another page to save these data, when the user click in send button, but I presume the ajax call is not working and it's very simple.

```
$('#send').click(function(){        

    $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     data: {mouse: countClick, teclado: keyClick},
     url: 'save.php',
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data){
        alert(data);
     },
     error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
     }
    });
});
```

But none alerts and console log is being shown. Do I need to "close" a form between button tag and specify `method` and `action`?

```
<form method="POST" action="#">
 <button id="send"> Send Data </button>
</form>
```

Or that's not a rule, I don't need a form to make ajax call and send the data?!

Comment: What is the console showing?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Sorry guys, I wanted to say :"Nothing is being shown"

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily need a form for an ajax call.

1. Your counter variables do not have scope within the $("#send").click method,  they are undefined outside document.ready method
2. Since you're using Ajax to post, you need to prevent form from submitting automatically when clicking on send button. Since you didn't use button type="button", it defaulted to button type ="submit".

Here's the solution that works

```js
var countClick = 0;
var keyClick = 0;


$(document).ready(function(){


    $("body").mousedown(function(){
        countClick ++;          
    });


    $("body").keypress(function(){
         keyClick ++;               
    });


    $("body").bind('keyup', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode >= 37 && e.keyCode <= 40){
          keyClick ++;
        }
    }); 


});

   

 $('#send').click(function(event){        
   

     $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     data: {mouse: countClick, teclado: keyClick},
     url: 'save.php',
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data){
        alert(data);
     },
     error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
     }
    });
        
      
      event.preventDefault();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="#">
 <button id="send" type="button"> Send Data </button>
</form>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ajanth2012/pen/MXaPpp)

Comment: After I made the corretions, the log stopped in `error: function (e)`

Comment: `{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}` What's that?

Comment: Verify if your save.php is working fine by maybe posting to that url from postman or similar tool. I don't think the js/html part has bugs now

Comment: Even the PHP is not working, Should I not getting a alert about data? The pointer is stopping error function

Comment: Only if your save.php works fine, you will get the alert. I have only given solution for the js and html issues I found